# Transposing a sparse matrix using linked lists (Traversal problems)

Tags: c++, matrix, traversal, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to transpose a sparse matrix in c++. I'm struggling with the traversal of the new transposed matrix. I want to enter everything from the first row of the matrix to the first column of the new matrix.

Each row has the column index the number should be in and the number itself.

Input:

colInd num colInd num colInd num

Input:

1 1 2 2 3 3

1 4 2 5 3 6

1 7 2 8 3 9

Output:

1 1 2 4 3 7

1 2 2 5 3 8

1 3 2 6 3 9

How do I make the list traverse down the first column inserting the first element as it goes then go back to the top inserting down the second column. Apologies if this is two hard to follow. But all I want help with is traversing the Transposed matrix to be in the right place at the right time inserting a nz(non zero) object in the right place.

Here is my code

```
list<singleRow> tran;
//Finshed reading so transpose

for (int i = 0; i < rows.size(); i++){ // Initialize transposed matrix
    singleRow trow;
    tran.push_back(trow);
}

list<singleRow>::const_iterator rit;
list<singleRow>::const_iterator trowit; 
int rowind;
for (rit = rows.begin(), rowind = 1; rit != rows.end(); rit++, rowind++){//rit = row iterator
    singleRow row = *rit;
    singleRow::const_iterator nzit;
    trowit = tran.begin(); //Start at the beginning of the list of rows
    trow = *trowit;
    for (nzit = row.begin(); nzit != row.end(); nzit++){//nzit = non zero iterator
            int col = nzit->getCol();
            double val = nzit->getVal();
            trow.push_back(nz(rowind,val)); //How do I attach this to tran so that it goes in the right place?
            trowit++;
    }
}
```

Comment: list is a really poor choice for matrices ( in fact, list is a poor choice for pretty much everything these days ), is there a particular reason for why you're using it?

Answer (score 1):

Your representation of the matrix is inefficient: it doesn't use the fact that the matrix is sparse. I say so because it includes all the rows of the matrix, even if most of them are zero (empty), like it usually happens with sparse matrices.

Your representation is also hard to work with. So i suggest converting the representation first (to a regular 2-D array), transposing the matrix, and convert back.

(Edited:)
Alternatively, you can change the representation, for example, like this:

Input: rowInd colInd num

```
1 1 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
2 1 4
2 2 5
2 3 6
3 1 7
3 2 8
3 3 9
```

Output:

```
1 1 1
2 1 2
3 1 3
1 2 4
2 2 5
3 2 6
1 3 7
2 3 8
3 3 9
```

The code would be something like this:

```
struct singleElement {int row, col; double val;};
list<singleElement> matrix_input, matrix_output;

...
// Read input matrix from file or some such

list<singleElement>::const_iterator i;
for (i = matrix_input.begin(); i != matrix_input.end(); ++i)
{
    singleElement e = *i;
    std::swap(e.row, e.col);
    matrix_output.push_back(e);
}
```

Comment: I know I just picked a simple to understand sparse matrix (which is not actually sparse) to make it easy to understand!

Comment: Whereas I agree that his representation is really not the best, I have yet to see practically relevant sparse matrices with a complete row of zeros (thus being a singular matrix). Ok, I'm sure they exist in certain application domains. But with numerical linear algebra being a very common use case for sparse matrices, I at least don't agree with zero-rows happening *"usually"*. But it could just be a question of the application domain one is used to.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of [list-of-list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#List_of_lists_.28LIL.29) representation for a sparse matrix is poor for transposition. Sometimes, when considering algorithms and data structures, the best thing to do is to take the hit for transforming your data structure into one better suited for your algorithm than to mangle your algorithm to work with the wrong data structure.

In this case you could, for example, read your matrix into a [coordinate list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Coordinate_list_.28COO.29) representation which would be very easy to transpose, then write into whatever representation you like.  If space is a challenge, then you might need to do this chunk by chunk, allocating new columns in your target representation 1 by 1 and deallocating columns in your old representation as you go.